# is it possible to remove/show button when user End the chat from the top right ( X ) close button in salesforce Einstein bot

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

is it possible to remove/show survey button when user close the chat from the top right ( X )  close button in salesforce Einstein bot

[close chat dailog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/716Lh.png)

[Wanted to show buttons like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K7Ho.png)

wanted to remove survay button when chat users timeout or some error occures